# UIBeziarPaths in iOS

Tags: ios

Is there any way to figure out the points that comprise the UIBeziarPath? It looks like you can't backtrack and see what's already there. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the easiest solution, but check out the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720398/how-to-use-cgpathapply-properly). The question has a response that is [just a link](http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=1312) with no other info. It has a pretty good suggestion.